# Spring приложение и tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

Допустим я собрал `jar` по [туториалу](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) с офф сайта `spring.io`. У меня есть папка с `application`-сервером `tomcat`. Как мне сделать так, чтобы собранный мной `jar` заработал под `tomcat` ? Просто положить его в папку `lib` ? Внутри `jar` надо указывать какую-то информацию о `tomcat` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтоб запустить на `tomcat`-е Вам нужно собрать `war`.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html

В принципе у спринга есть свой встроенный `tomcat` можно и сам `jar` запустить